# Funcion genera graficas sin borrar las anteriores

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Cada vez que doy click en el boton la grafica vuelve a generarse sin desaparecer la anterior, comprendo este problema pero nunca habia usado js asi que quiero saber como hacer para que la grafica simplemente se actualice y no genere otra mas.

```js
function datos(){
    var hr1 = document.getElementById('hr1').value;
    var hr13 = document.getElementById('hr13').value;
    var hr36 = document.getElementById('hr36').value;
    var hrtdo = document.getElementById('hrtdo').value;
    

var chartData =[hr1,hr13,hr36,hrtdo];

var margin = {
    top:30,
    right:30,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 50
}

var height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var width = 800 - margin.right - margin.left;
//var barWidth = 35;
//var barOffset = 5;

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,d3.max(chartData)])
.range([0, height]);

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(d3.range(0, chartData.length))
.rangeBands([0, width]);

var colors = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, chartData.length])
.range(['#B03648','#SSA4243B'])

d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
.attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate('+margin.left+ ',' + margin.top+')')
.style('background', '#f4f4f4')
.selectAll('rect')
.data(chartData)
.enter().append('rect')
.style('fill', function(d,i){

    return colors(i);
})
.attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
.attr('height', function(d){

    return yScale(d);
})
.attr('x', function(d, i){
return xScale(i);

})
.attr('y', function(d){
    return height - yScale(d);
})

var vScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,d3.max(chartData)])
.range([height, 0]);

var hScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(["1 hora","2-3 horas","4-6 horas","TODO EL DIA"])
.rangeBands([0, width]);

//V axis
var vAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(vScale)
.orient('left')
.ticks(5)
.tickPadding(5)
// V GUIDE
var vGuide = d3.select('svg')
.append('g')
vAxis(vGuide)
vGuide.attr('transform','translate('+margin.left+','+margin.top+')')
vGuide.selectAll('path')
.style('fill','none')
.style('stroke', '#000')
vGuide.selectAll('line')
.style('stroke','#000')

//H axis
var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(hScale)
.orient('bottom')
.tickValues(hScale.domain().filter(function(d, i){
return !(i % (chartData.length/4));

}));
// H GUIDE
var hGuide = d3.select('svg')
.append('g')
hAxis(hGuide)
hGuide.attr('transform','translate('+margin.left+ ','+(height + margin.top
    )+')')
hGuide.selectAll('path')
.style('fill','none')
.style('stroke', '#000')
hGuide.selectAll('line')
.style('stroke','#000')



}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Generador de widget</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index_style.css" />
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" language="JavaScript"></script>

</head>

<body bgcolor = "white"> 
 <div id="menu">
            
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../Circle menu/index.htm">Menu principal</a></li>
                <li><a href="../LIQUID GAUGE/index.html">Grafica de porcentajes</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
<font color = "#B03648" face = "arial" size = "5"><center><h1><u><b><i>Generador de widget</b></i></u></h1>



<form name="form1"  method = "get">
     Clientes que pagaron 1 a 2 horas.
      <input type = "decimal" id = "hr1" name = "hr1"><br>
  Clientes que pagaron 3 a 4 horas.
   <input type = "decimal" id = "hr13" name = "hr13"><br>
   Clientes que pagaron 5 a 6 hrs.
   <input type = "decimal" id = "hr36" name = "hr36"><br>
   Clientes que pagaron por todo el dia.
   <input type = "decimal" id = "hrtdo" name = "hrtdo"><br>
   <input type = "button" value = "calcular" onclick="datos()">
</form>
</font>

<div id="chart">
<script src="gdpBarGraph.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que la api de d3.js tendrá alguna opción, pero vaciando chart antes de llenarlo te funciona. 
añade al inicio de datos

```
 document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML  ="";
```

```js
function datos(){
    var hr1 = document.getElementById('hr1').value;
    var hr13 = document.getElementById('hr13').value;
    var hr36 = document.getElementById('hr36').value;
    var hrtdo = document.getElementById('hrtdo').value;
    

var chartData =[hr1,hr13,hr36,hrtdo];

var margin = {
    top:30,
    right:30,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 50
}

var height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var width = 800 - margin.right - margin.left;
//var barWidth = 35;
//var barOffset = 5;

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,d3.max(chartData)])
.range([0, height]);

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(d3.range(0, chartData.length))
.rangeBands([0, width]);

var colors = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, chartData.length])
.range(['#B03648','#SSA4243B'])
 document.getElementById('chart').innerHTML  ="";
d3.selectAll('#chart').append('svg')
.attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate('+margin.left+ ',' + margin.top+')')
.style('background', '#f4f4f4')
.selectAll('rect')
.data(chartData)
.enter().append('rect')
.style('fill', function(d,i){

    return colors(i);
})
.attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
.attr('height', function(d){

    return yScale(d);
})
.attr('x', function(d, i){
return xScale(i);

})
.attr('y', function(d){
    return height - yScale(d);
})

var vScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,d3.max(chartData)])
.range([height, 0]);

var hScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(["1 hora","2-3 horas","4-6 horas","TODO EL DIA"])
.rangeBands([0, width]);

//V axis
var vAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(vScale)
.orient('left')
.ticks(5)
.tickPadding(5)
// V GUIDE
var vGuide = d3.select('svg')
.append('g')
vAxis(vGuide)
vGuide.attr('transform','translate('+margin.left+','+margin.top+')')
vGuide.selectAll('path')
.style('fill','none')
.style('stroke', '#000')
vGuide.selectAll('line')
.style('stroke','#000')

//H axis
var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(hScale)
.orient('bottom')
.tickValues(hScale.domain().filter(function(d, i){
return !(i % (chartData.length/4));

}));
// H GUIDE
var hGuide = d3.select('svg')
.append('g')
hAxis(hGuide)
hGuide.attr('transform','translate('+margin.left+ ','+(height + margin.top
    )+')')
hGuide.selectAll('path')
.style('fill','none')
.style('stroke', '#000')
hGuide.selectAll('line')
.style('stroke','#000')



}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Generador de widget</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index_style.css" />
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" language="JavaScript"></script>

</head>

<body bgcolor = "white"> 
 <div id="menu">
            
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../Circle menu/index.htm">Menu principal</a></li>
                <li><a href="../LIQUID GAUGE/index.html">Grafica de porcentajes</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
<font color = "#B03648" face = "arial" size = "5"><center><h1><u><b><i>Generador de widget</b></i></u></h1>



<form name="form1"  method = "get">
     Clientes que pagaron 1 a 2 horas.
      <input type = "decimal" id = "hr1" name = "hr1"><br>
  Clientes que pagaron 3 a 4 horas.
   <input type = "decimal" id = "hr13" name = "hr13"><br>
   Clientes que pagaron 5 a 6 hrs.
   <input type = "decimal" id = "hr36" name = "hr36"><br>
   Clientes que pagaron por todo el dia.
   <input type = "decimal" id = "hrtdo" name = "hrtdo"><br>
   <input type = "button" value = "calcular" onclick="datos()">
</form>
</font>

<div id="chart">
<script src="gdpBarGraph.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```